# How can I access the data from new column to existing table in Magento2

Tags: magento-2.0

I have added a new column (PIN_ID) to the existing magento 2 table('sales_order') by 'Setup/UpgradeSchema',
what's the best practice to access(get or retrieve) the data?

PS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using ObjectManager you can access your custom field of table,

```
            $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
            $order = $objectManager->get('Magento\Sales\Model\Order');
            $order_information = $order->loadByIncrementId($order_id);
            $orderItems = $order_information->getAllItems();

            foreach ($orderItems as $item) {
                  $itemSku = $item->getPinId();
            }
```

Comment: Regardless if the answer is right or not I'm not sure if `$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); is a good practice` for me sounds more to a shorthand than a real solution. I guess that the correct way to do that is injecting the order as factory or repository in the constructor IMO.

Comment: Hi Rakesh Jesadiy,

It's work!!!

            $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
            $order = $objectManager->get('Magento\Sales\Model\Order');
            $order_information = $order->loadByIncrementId(3);
            $orderItems = $order_information->getAllItems();
            echo('Order:'.$order->getPinId().'<br />');

Thanks
PS